# Can you please help identify these fonts?

Tags: fonts, typography, font-identification

What are the fonts used in these labels? There are three different fonts used here.

The font used on the 1st and 3rd line are the same in all the labels (`NO. 02, NO. 19 & HERB, SEASONING` etc). It's kind of like a typewriter font.

The font used on the second line is also the same in all labels (`BASIL, SEA SALT` etc).

and the font used on the fourth line is the same in all labels (`ALL NATURAL, EXTRA DARK, PURE & NATURAL`)

Does anyone know that fonts are these?

`https://www.myfonts.com/WhatTheFont` isn't of much help, since these most probably are fonts that aren't included in their catalogue.

[image]

[image]

[image]

[image]

[image]

[image]

[image]

[image]

[image]

[image]

Comment: I recommend try all major font detection sites. WhatTheFont fails many times. The other 2 are not in good quality. I will try to find.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Font used for main product names (`BASIL, SEA SALT`) is probably
**Old Newspaper Types**

[image]

The font used for `NO. 02, NO. 19 & HERB, SEASONING` and the digits
is probably **Telegraphem**

[image]

Both are available at `dafont.com`.

---

The closest match that I could find for those white colored texts
(`PURE & NATURAL, EXTRA DARK, ALL NATURAL`) on black background
shape/patch is **Hillman / Hillman MN** family at `myfonts.com`. It
looks a bit similar but has extra weight and some other differences.

[image]

Further, if you want, you can visit `dafont.com` and go to `Fancy > Typewriter` category and preview all available fonts. There are many similar fonts, if not same. **It could be a possibility** that many of them are based on the font being used on the bottles. Or maybe the font used on the bottles is a custom variation of some unknown (unknown to me) font family. Two similar I found are `Stichy Times` and `Type Wrong`:

[image]

[image]

*Note that PURE & NATURAL and a few other texts have been written using two different fonts for different bottles. For example, the font used for PURE & NATURAL in white color behind dark shape/patch is **not** Telegraphem.*

*Make sure you read about their licenses and usage terms & conditions and pricing. You can try at the site to preview them.*

---

Also, in case you're looking for free fonts, you can search `IM Fell` at [Google Fonts](http://fonts.google.com). You'll find a few fonts with somewhat similar look and feel.

**Note:** When you use font finder sites, I would recommended to try more than one site. For example, I couldn't find these fonts using *WhatTheFont*. I used *FONT IDENTIFIER at* `fontsquirrel.com` and it worked with a few tries.